# Professor says we can’t initialize array. Is this possible?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

So my class is currently doing stuff with arrays and stacks. The professor gave us our choice of language (he uses c++) and I chose Java. He is saying when we create our array, we CANNOT initialize the array to 0 or null.

Is this even possible? From my understanding, uses arrays automatically initialize to 0 unless specified in Java.

EDIT: I was not clear enough. The assignment says “you may not initialize the array to null, zero, or any other value”

Comment: `int[] arr = { 1 };` there is an array, it is not initialized to `0` or `null`.

Comment: There seems like information missing from the question. Please tell us more of what is going on and *exactly* what restrictions you've been given. You may be misinterpreting things.

Comment: "Cannot" as in it is not possible, or "cannot" as in not allowed to?  There's a difference.  Java as you point out always initializes arrays to 0 or null, so there might be something else intended.

Comment: If you want to have some fun, pick Haskell instead.

Comment: As per the rules of the assignment, we are not allowed to intialize the array “to null, zero, or any other value”.

Comment: This information is too important to be buried in comments and should be a part of your original question. Please [edit] the question. Clarity is key, else why even ask it?

Comment: Sounds like maybe the idea is for you to **learn not to rely on** an array having been previously initialized (to either zero or nulls) for the correct operation of your algorithms: an algorithm should be written so that it explicitly **sets every cell** to the correct value (whether zero or non-zero), rather than assume that it need only set those whose values should be non-zero.

Comment: Sorry about that Hover. Edited it just now

Comment: The Java Language Specification [mandates that arrays are initialized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) with (depending on the type) with `0`, `false` or `null`. If your professor claims this is not the case, then he does not teach Java.

Comment: Well, if you write `int[] array = new int[100];'  then **you**, technically, haven't initialized the array.  But, truth-in-advertising, the **Java system**, technically (and  _unavoidably_), initializes it to all zeros for you.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine, proving it's possible:

```
public class ArrayInitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] y = {0};
        int[] z = null;
    }
}
```

If your professor is telling you that you can't, he's saying that you're not allowed to for assignments in his class.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. He is not allowing it for his class. So I was just confused on how else I am supposed to create an array in the class constructor without it being intialize to anything. So we can manipulate the array in other methods